# xcode5 cocoapods original project missing

Tags: ios, xcode, project, cocoapods

> **update 20131117:** Now it works. I opened it again with the Foobar.xcworkspace and everything is fine. Strange error. Sometimes you need just to sleep a nigth and problems are solved... :)

I am new to cocoapods. I installed it to get the `AFNetworking` library, which worked fine.

When I now start my Foobar.xcworkspace my original projectfiles are missing.  I am not sure if this is the correct behaviour. I cannot believe that I have to switch always betweeen Foobar.xcodeproj and Foobar.xcworkspace to do coding and testing.

How do I get back my original projectfiles for coding and can work with cocoapods together?

Original Foobar.xcodeproj project structure (in the Project Navigator):

```
- Foobar
  - Foobar                   # This Branch is missing in .xcworkspace
    - Classes
    - Supporting Files
    - Vendors
  - FoobarTests
  - Frameworks
  - Products
```

Foobar.xcworkspace projectfiles, where the original files are missing (in the Project Navigator):

```
- Foobar.xcodeproj          # opening this file leads to an empty editor
- Pods
  - Podfile
  - Frameworks
  - Pods
  - Products
  - Target Support Files
```

Comment: did you find an answer? I have the same problem.

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs as described in the update. I just opened it later that day and it worked. No Glue why.